# Haskell: Best way to search a list of large size

Tags: list, search, haskell, functional-programming

I have a list of 100K+ elements, this is a finite list. Currently I am using the Data.List function elem. When looking at the Data.List information page there is also find and filter. Would one of these be faster than the elem function?

Comment: Lists are just linked lists.  There is no way to get better than O(n) performance without adding some structure.  You could convert your lists in to one of the many other structures such as sets, hash sets, bloom filters, etc.

Comment: I'm surprised no one mentioned using Data.Vector and traditional search algos.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Could you explain what you mean by "traditional search algos" in that context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case we haven't beat the dead horse quite enough...

There is a huge performance difference with different set representations.  As an example (which might or might not match your use case) consider taking a list of 200K random elements and a computation to determine the membership of 200 random elements.

I've implemented three obvious ways to do this - using `elem` over the list, converting to a `HashSet` and checking for membership, and performing a hybrid of Bloom Filters and a Hash Set.  The benchmark shows the list solution is 3 orders of magnitude slower than the hash set, which is about 2x slower than the hybrid.

```
benchmarking list
mean: 460.7106 ms, lb 459.2952 ms, ub 462.8491 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 8.741096 ms, lb 6.293703 ms, ub 12.23082 ms, ci 0.950

benchmarking hashset
mean: 175.2730 us, lb 173.9140 us, ub 177.0802 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 7.966790 us, lb 6.391454 us, ub 10.25774 us, ci 0.950

benchmarking bloom+hashset
mean: 88.22402 us, lb 87.35856 us, ub 89.66884 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 5.642663 us, lb 3.793715 us, ub 8.264222 us, ci 0.950
```

And the code:

```
import qualified Data.HashSet as Set
import           Data.HashSet (Set)
import qualified Data.BloomFilter as BF
import qualified Data.BloomFilter.Easy as BF
import           Data.BloomFilter (Bloom)
import           Data.BloomFilter.Hash as H2
import           Data.Hashable as H1
import Criterion.Main
import System.Random

data MySet a = MS (Set a) (Bloom a)

fromList :: (H2.Hashable a, H1.Hashable a, Ord a) => [a] -> MySet a
fromList as =
    let hs = Set.fromList as
        bf = BF.easyList 0.2 as
    in hs `seq` bf `seq` MS hs bf

member :: (H2.Hashable a, H1.Hashable a, Ord a) => a -> MySet a -> Bool
member e (MS hs bf)
    | BF.elemB e bf = Set.member e hs
    | otherwise      = False

main = do
  list   <- take 200000 `fmap` randomsIO :: IO [Int]
  xs     <- take 200    `fmap` randomsIO
  let hs  = Set.fromList list
      bhs = fromList list
  defaultMain
        [ bench "list" $ nf (map (`elem` list)) xs
        , bench "hashset" $ nf (map (`Set.member` hs)) xs
        , bench "bloom+hashset" $ nf (map (`member` bhs)) xs
        ]

randomsIO = randoms `fmap` newStdGen
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I am having issues understanding it. Could you explain you benchmarks a little bit more? Also with your hashable data structure does that take a key and value? If so could I make a hashable Sting String?

Comment: The first benchmark is just a traversal of the 200K element list for each of the 200 test elements.  The second benchmark hashes the element and checks for its membership in a binary tree.  The third solution hashes the element, checks if it appears in a bloom filter, then only if the bloom filter (which can have false positives) returns true it checks if said element is in a binary tree.

Comment: If you wish to hash two strings then use a tuple, the type `(String,String)` is Hashable.

Comment: The reason I asked about the hashable String String is I look at the calls and it is looking for a key as where I want to search by the value not the key. I was just planning on make the key and value the same.

Comment: Also each time I am searching over my list right now it is not always the same size of search element. Like my first one could be 4 long and the next could be 10 long.

Comment: So in other words you don't want a set at all. You want a map (aka a dictionary)?

Comment: Pretty much, I was just going by others advice at first with the list idea. I did work it that when I got a word to find I went through the big list to find all strings of the same length into a new list so I would not have to check every element even ones that werent the same length. I thought this would be faster and more efficient.

Comment: Use a `HashMap` from the `unordered-containers` package.  That way you won't have to check all the elements every time - you compute a hash (an `Int`) once and compare that until you find the right bucket.

Comment: Could I pull the file into my program into a list then use the fromList function with Hashmap to put it into a hasmap? Also with the member function within Hashmap wants a key. Is this a index value of the String or would this be the String I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

In each case you're going to require a linear traversal of the list. If you're going to be checking for containment repeatedly you should change to a more efficient structure. If you just need to do a single lookup then `O(n)` worst case is the best you can get—just look for your element as you create them.

If your types are ordered (instantiate `Ord`) then you should use `Set` from the `containers` package (it's part of the Haskell Platform).

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

mySet :: Set.Set Elems
mySet = Set.fromList bigList -- expensive, eventually requires a 1 linear traversal

-- cheaper!
checkElems :: [Elem] -> Set.Set Elems -> [Bool]
checkElems es s = map (\e -> Set.member e s) es
```

If `Ord` isn't possible, you may be able to using hashing instead via the data structures in `unordered-containers`. In that package we have `Data.HashSet` which is effectively identical to `Data.Set` except it requires the (sometimes more liberal, sometimes faster) `Hashable` instance instead of `Ord`.

If your `Elem` type is actually `Int` then `Data.IntSet` is also a great choice.

Finally, it's worth noting that while `Set` is an optimized structure for checking membership, it does throw away repeats. If repeats are valuable you will want to examine other data types or some kinds of preprocessing. Sets with repeats are often called Bags and can be simulated (with similar performance characteristics) by using the `Data.Map`, `Data.HashMap`, and `Data.IntMap` modules. In this case, you store your list as a `Data.Map.Map Elem Count` and check for membership by seeing if a particular key is being used in the result map.

Comment: So with Data.Set and the checkElems function from above would this be able to pass in a [String] and a string. I am looking for the string within the [String]. You are also on the right track for me as I will be doing multiple look ups with the data structure. I have looked at HashMap data structure and have some questions about it HashMap. I was thinking about passing the 100K line file into a list then pull that list into the HashMap but I didnt know if that was a good way.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the definitions:

```
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem _ []     = False
elem x (y:ys) = x == y || elem x ys

find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
find p = listToMaybe . filter p

filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter p [] = []
filter p (x:xs) = if p x then x : filter p xs else filter p xs
```

Quite clearly, `find` and `filter` have the same complexity.  The `elem` function has the same basic recursion pattern as `filter`, so it also has the same complexity.  So really, it doesn't matter much which one you use, all of these have worst case `O(n)` complexity.  If you're just testing membership, then `elem` should be your function of choice.  If you're doing a lot more than just that, you might want to consider switching to a `Vector`, `Set`, or other data structure better optimized for what you're doing.  Lists in Haskell are great for nondeterminism and working with small amounts of data, but when you have a significant number of data points their inefficiencies become very noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

They do different things. `filter` simply removes elements according to a predicate. This is going to be slower then `elem` in all cases since it must traverse the entire list and check the predicate even if your element is at the head of the list.

`find` is just going to return an element, so it's going to be identical in performance for all intents and purposes.

So `elem`/`find` is probably around local maximum for efficiency of searching a list. But it's quite a pitiful local maximum.

On the other hand, if you're manipulating a lot of data, `[]` is probably the wrong choice. It's absolutely horrible from a cache perspective, and almost all operations are `O(n)`. It is after all, just a dumb singly-linked list. If you're doing a lot of membership checks, consider switching to `Data.Set`, a very painless transition.

Comment: `head . filter` will be equally cheap, though

Comment: @J.Abrahamson That's true, in this case though, why not just use `find`?

Comment: I don't think there's much a reason to prefer any of those over `elem` for performance reasons and `elem` reads better.

Comment: @jozefg `find` doesn't return the index, it returns the first element satisfying a condition.

Answer (score 0):

For that many elements, you probably want to use a data structure that does sub-linear searching.  My go-to library for Haskell data structure is [Edison](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/EdisonCore).  The GHC includes [Data.Set](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Set.html) which will still be  sub-linear and the platform has [unordered-containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers) and it is supposed to be quite fast.